# My PIC16F628As keeping dying with a Pickit3

Tags: microcontroller, pickit

I have hooked up my PIC16F628As to my PICKIT like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjs3kG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Yet 3 already died after a few writes, yet the datasheet claimed to support thousands of writes.
I get the following Error after a few (3-4) writes:

```
Address: 0 Expected Value: 3fff Received Value: 2ffe
```

I wired it up according to specification, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you use a pullup between VDD and /MCLR? Did you decouple VDD to VCC? There is no capacitor in your schematic.

Comment: Its wired exactly like the schematic. Is there supposed to be? I went off the manual of the pickit and there was no mention of a pullup or a cap. Could that have killed the pics?

Comment: Maybe the pics are still alive. You may get reading errors due to unstable Vdd. Do apply the recommended usage for the PICKKit3 as shown in an answer below. Place a 100nF capacitor between Vdd and Vss as close as possible to the PIC16F628.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should review the [recommended usage for the PICKit3](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/50002010b.pdf), a helpful poster from Microchip.

[image: MPLABX PICKit usage instructions]

This shows the MCLR pull-up which is required in all normal circumstances. You’ll also need a capacitor between Vcc and GND for any modern IC.

Comment: But this guide itself discurages diodes pullups and capactitors. I am currently using this method, which doesnt need extrenal power and was able to revive my pic:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAgKxxoEDa4

Comment: @user2741831 the Microchip guide says you should use a pull-up on MCLR. It does not discourage this. Excess resistance and capacitance is discouraged on *other* pins, as this could alter the digital signalling from the PICKit.